# How to create two partitions?

Tags: partitioning

I have a 80Gb HDD with one partition for Ubuntu and want to partition it into two partitions 60G/20G.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please edit your answer and tell us if this is a dual boot system or not and if it is what will you be booting besides ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: Make sure that the drive is empty; otherwise make sure that you have a complete backup of its content, because creating a partition **will erase all data on the drive**.

Open Dash, and search for Gparted, and click on it.  If its not installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Once installed open the application, and enter your password.  Once it open, follow the step below:

If the drive is new, Click on Device, and choose Create Partition Table; otherwise skip to the step in the third image.

[image]

Keep the Default, and click Apply

[image]

Right click on the Unallocated space, and choose New

[image]

Create a 60GB partition.  Once you enter all the info, click Add

[image]

Then Right click on the Unallocated space, and choose New

[image]

Create a 20GB partition.  Once you enter all the info, click Add

[image]

Click on the Green check mark to Apply pending operations

[image]

And just click Apply to start.

[image]

Once done, just click Close, and that's it.

[image]

Comment: Creating a partition doesn't necessarily "erase all data on the drive".  One can normally shrink an existing partition to leave unallocated space and create a new partition in this space.  Your example actually creates a partition table - which is a different story.

Comment: You're right in a way.  The OP has a drive that she/he want to create 2 partitions.  Without knowing any other details, creating these partitions will erase all data on the drive, hence the answer would be the correct way to create the partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Live-CD with Gparted to shrink the 80 GB partition to 60 GB and then create a 20 GB partition in the unallocated space that the shrinking procedure creates.

Information on the use of Gparted, plus a number of references to how-to sites and video tutorials, can be found at:  http://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/manual-partitioning/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot partition your drive unless you unmount it(and you cannot unmount that partition which has the current OS installed on it). So make a bootable disk/usb stick first, then boot-in from it and try the "G-Parted partition editor" and partition your drive however you want :)